# CSS Background wont display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, adobe-brackets

I changed my main image to a css background property but when i open my index.html the image does not show up.

I used the following property inside my custom.css file.

```
background: url("/img/banner-bg.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 80%;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center center;
background-size: contain;
```

However the weird is when i try to live preview with brackets it is showing up just fine.

Comment: can you post your folder structure

Comment: did you set content to this element or did you set width and height values in css for this element?

Comment: i have updated with all properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put trailing dots before your img folder path and make sure the file is in the folder

If that doesn't work, find the image in explorer, right click to get the properties and find the full image path. Use the full image path preceded by

```
 file://
```

e.g.

```
 background-image:url("file:///C:/Users/Rachel/SkyDrive/webdesign/img/banner-bg.jpg");
```

and that should work

Comment: here there are:  background: url("/img/banner-bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 80%;
 background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;

Comment: I mean that the image displays just fine inside brackets but when i open the index.html in browser the image wont display. I am using background-image now

Comment: Make sure all your CSS before is correctly closed off with curly brackets and colons

Comment: No, well try it with a random image, but it should show

Comment: currently its local. do you think i should try uploading it to see if it works that way?

Comment: Yes do that, even to Dropbox

Comment: refresh the page i added bootstrap and font awesome

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is a slash at the start of the string. There's a difference between if you start path with slash or not.

For example if you working on localhost and path to the folder where the css file exists looks like that:

```
localhost/yourProjectFolder/and/all/of/subfolders/
```

With slash:

```
background: url("/img/banner-bg.jpg"); 
//returns absolute path : localhost/img/banner-bg.jpg
```

Without slash:

```
background: url("img/banner-bg.jpg"); 
// returns absolute path : localhost/yourProjectFolder/and/all/of/subfolders/img/banner-bg.jpg
```